# How do I escape single quotes in data which is of hstore datatype using Pentaho

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, hstore

I am trying to read hstore data from source and insert into target hstore column. But for some weird reason the data has some single quotes in it and  I cannot delete or remove them. Source hstore data looks something like

```
Value 1: "Target_Payment_Type"=>"Auto_Renew", "Target_Membership_term"=>"1 Year" 
Value 2: "Target_Payment_Type"=>"'Auto_Renew'", "Target_Membership_term"=>"'1 Year'"
```

The transformation works fine with the 1st value but fails when at Value2. Can could anyone suggest me a way I can escape the single quotes which may appear in data using pentaho or postgresql (source & target database). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At least, you can use postgres replace function in Table Input step:

```
SELECT
,all_your_non_string_columns
,replace(string_column,'''', '') //note that '''' represents '
FROM 
your_table
```

Real solution you could find in up-to-date driver perhaps.

Comment: I don't want to replace I want to escape the quotes and pass it in the hstore value.